# print style sheet for blogger

Tags: html, css, printing, blogger

I am working on print style sheet for blogger for my site: http://www.problogbooster.com/

I almost done but the problem is about URL printing. When I debug my print CSS it shows URL for post images too.

I have used following CSS:

```
.post-body a:link[href^="http://"]:after {content: " (" attr(href) ") "; font-size: 11px;}

.post-body a:link[href^="https://"]:after {content: " (" attr(href) ") "; font-size: 11px;}

.post-body a:[href^="#"]:after {content: "";}
```

You can see it in Chrome print style debugger by inspecting or with CSS too.

Anybody knows the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your images are actually wrapped in an `<a>` tag. If you remove that from the markup, it should fix the problem.

Comment: I also tried with that too.. hope you could suggest different from that... thanks though :)